# App in React Native after won't open in device after build successfull

Tags: node.js, react-native, metro-bundler

It will show like this after build successful
[Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmkk5.png)
Installed on 1 device.

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 22s 27 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 26 up-to-date
>   The system cannot find the path specified. info Starting the app
>   (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools/platform-tools/adb
>   shell am start -n com.sae/com.sae.MainActivity...

But what is "**The system cannot find the path specified**" ?

How can I fix it ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Is it running on simulator?

Comment: No,I didn't tried

Comment: can you try plz.

Comment: dont have simulator that is why im not tried

Comment: anyother solution?